# How to display an image selected using PushButton in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface

I'm working on basic GUI in Matlab-2012a. I wanted to display the select and display the image using a push button.

Here's my code:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global TrainingData;
global filenames;

TrainingData={};

[filenames, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.png';'*.bmp'});

if ~ischar(filenames) % on cancel press you display a message of error with errordlg
errordlg('Error!','No file selected'); % displays an error message by means of errordlg function
 return;
end

axes(handles.myaxesImage);
imshow(filenames);
```

I can browse the image, but I'm not able to display the same. I'm getting the following Error Message:

```
Reference to non-existent field 'axesImage'.

Error in GUI>pushbutton2_Callback (line 93)
axes(handles.axesImage);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
    feval(varargin{:});

Error in GUI (line 42)
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)GUI('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Any Suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well is it handles.axesimage or handles.myaxesimage? The error message and your code do not fit. Moreover looks like you need a call to imread before using imshow.

Comment: @Benoit_11 Its 'handles.axesimage'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code

> axes(handles.myaxesImage);

MATLAB said

> Reference to non-existent field 'axesImage'

So there is a problem for MATLAB to recognize object **handles.myaxesImage**

**Because it doesn't exist!**

---

Here is an example

In the .m file of my GUI

I want to show image on axes whose tag is axes1

```html
function openFile_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to openFile (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%== GUI get file in the folder ==%
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile({'*.tif';'*.jpg';'*.png'},'Select a image file');

%== Create a object handles.img to load image ==%
handles.img  = imread(FileName);  

%== call axes whose tag is axes1 to show image ==%
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(handles.img);

guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Next time you want to use any varable in GUI

Don't forget to check whether that object **exists**

Hope it helps